# The requested look up key was not found in any activation content

Tags: windows-xp, installation

After installing Windows XP Professional and running updates that include IE8 I am receiving this error message when trying to open Windows Updates. I've tried install twice on the same machine with the same errors. I have other machines of the same exact hardware and installation process with no issues. Any thoughts?

Comment: Was this an imaged machine or a fresh install?

Comment: Fresh install - no images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has broken updates today. After more time more and more machines I was updating starting failing the same way. After choosing to Uninstall IE8 from the machine the error cleared. I was then able to continue with updates. A very odd issue. Who knows what Microsoft broke today but let's hope it gets fixed soon.